# SQL Invalid Column Name Issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I am getting an invalid column name error and I can't understand why...

[image]

```
SELECT TOP (1000) i.[t207f005_classification_code]
      ,i.[t207f010_sort_key]
      ,i.[t207f015_date_effective]
      ,i.[t207f020_rate]
      ,i.[t207f025_annual_rate]
      ,i.[t207f030_rate_high]
      ,i.[t207f035_annual_rate_high]
      ,i.[DEXLastUpdateDt]
      ,RANK () OVER ( 
            PARTITION BY i.[t207f005_classification_code]
            ORDER BY i.[t207f015_date_effective] ASC
        ) AS ClassificationRank
  FROM [DEX].[HrPayroll].[t207_classification_rate] i
  Left join 
  (SELECT [t207f005_classification_code]
          ,[t207f015_date_effective] - 1 as Date_To_Derived
          ,[t207f020_rate]
      ,RANK () OVER ( 
            PARTITION BY [t207f005_classification_code]
            ORDER BY [t207f015_date_effective] ASC
        ) - 1 AS NextClassificationRank
  FROM 
    [DEX].[HrPayroll].[t207_classification_rate]) h
  ON h.[t207f005_classification_code] = i.[t207f005_classification_code]
  AND ClassificationRank = h.NextClassificationRank

What I am trying to achieve is a table that just outputs:

i.[t207_classification_rate], 
i.[t207f015_date_effective], 
h.[Date_To_Derived], 
i.[t207f020_rate]
```

Effectively the date range the rate for each classification goes for.

Googling for answer and asking a colleague to help.  Can't work out the solution.

Answer (score 0):

The `rank` function is calculated in the `SELECT` statement and it's result is not visible in the `ON` one. You can see the [Logical Processing Order of the SELECT statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#logical-processing-order-of-the-select-statement):

> 1. FROM
> 2. ON
> 3. JOIN
> 4. WHERE
> 5. GROUP BY
> 6. WITH CUBE or WITH ROLLUP
> 7. HAVING
> 8. SELECT
> 9. DISTINCT
> 10. ORDER BY
> 11. TOP

To fix your issue you can try:

```
SELECT *
FROM 
(
    SELECT TOP (1000) [t207f005_classification_code]
                     ,[t207f010_sort_key]
                     ,[t207f015_date_effective]
                     ,[t207f020_rate]
                     ,[t207f025_annual_rate]
                     ,[t207f030_rate_high]
                     ,[t207f035_annual_rate_high]
                     ,[DEXLastUpdateDt]
                     ,RANK () OVER (PARTITION BY [t207f005_classification_code] ORDER BY [t207f015_date_effective] ASC) AS ClassificationRank
    FROM [DEX].[HrPayroll].[t207_classification_rate]
    ORDER BY ClassificationRank
) I
LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT [t207f005_classification_code]
          ,[t207f015_date_effective]
          ,[t207f020_rate]
          ,RANK () OVER ( PARTITION BY [t207f005_classification_code] ORDER BY [t207f015_date_effective] ASC) - 1 AS NextClassificationRank
   FROM [DEX].[HrPayroll].[t207_classification_rate]
) H
    ON I.[t207f005_classification_code] = H.[t207f005_classification_code]
    AND I.ClassificationRank = H.NextClassificationRank;
```

Also, you can use [LEAD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lead-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) and [LAG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) to get previous and next values. There is no need to use subqueries. Check this:

```
SELECT TOP (1000) [t207f005_classification_code]
                 ,[t207f010_sort_key]
                 ,[t207f015_date_effective]
                 ,[t207f020_rate]
                 ,[t207f025_annual_rate]
                 ,[t207f030_rate_high]
                 ,[t207f035_annual_rate_high]
                 ,[DEXLastUpdateDt]
                 ,RANK () OVER (PARTITION BY [t207f005_classification_code] ORDER BY [t207f015_date_effective] ASC) AS ClassificationRank
                 --
                 ,LEAD([t207f005_classification_code]) OVER (PARTITION BY [t207f005_classification_code] ORDER BY [t207f015_date_effective] ASC)
                 ,LEAD([t207f015_date_effective]) OVER (PARTITION BY [t207f005_classification_code] ORDER BY [t207f015_date_effective] ASC)
                 ,LEAD([t207f020_rate]) OVER (PARTITION BY [t207f005_classification_code] ORDER BY [t207f015_date_effective] ASC)
                 --
                 ,LAG([t207f005_classification_code]) OVER (PARTITION BY [t207f005_classification_code] ORDER BY [t207f015_date_effective] ASC)
                 ,LAG([t207f015_date_effective]) OVER (PARTITION BY [t207f005_classification_code] ORDER BY [t207f015_date_effective] ASC)
                 ,LAG([t207f020_rate]) OVER (PARTITION BY [t207f005_classification_code] ORDER BY [t207f015_date_effective] ASC)
FROM [DEX].[HrPayroll].[t207_classification_rate]
ORDER BY ClassificationRank
```

Comment: Thanks for your help so far mate.  I am in SSMS v18.3.1 and it says LEAD is not a recognised built-in function name...

Comment: @CarlBlunck You can try the first query then. Also, the SSMS version has nothing to do with the SQL Server version. To check your SQL Server version execute `SELECT @@VERSION`

Comment: Ah right.  Thanks.  On version Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP3-GDR) (KB4057113) - 10.50.6560.0 (X64)   Dec 28 2017 15:03:48   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 <X64> (Build 7601: Service Pack 1) (Hypervisor) .

Comment: Have updated my initial post to show what output I am wanting to get, wasn't complete initially.  Sorry.

Comment: @CarlBlunck if the first query is working, you can just add the columns you need.

Comment: 2008R2 ran *completely* out of support back in 2019, @CarlBlunck . You really should be looking to getting that upgrade path implemented ASAP. It is no longer a secure version of software.